# Finding the greatest number less than x and divisible by y

Tags: number-theory

We know nothing about x and y
and we have to write a function for finding the greatest number less than x and divisible by y-

x=16, y=4, ans=12

x=0, y=4 ans=-4

Please suggest some ideas..

Comment: One can use $y\lfloor\dfrac{x-1}{y}\rfloor$ for positive integer $x,y$.

Comment: @Oleg567 This is it. Please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

One can use $\;\;y\left\lfloor\dfrac{x-1}{y}\right\rfloor$ for positive integer $x,y$.

Comment: +1 This will work if the floor function is a black box. If not the OP will have to code it with a conditional that should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem would be to find the remainder on division of $x$ by $y$. More formally, define $k$ as: $k = x \% y$.

If $k = 0$, then we can output: $x - y$, else we can output: $x - k$. Hope this helps.

Comment: we don't know if k will be 0 or not

Comment: In that case, how are we able to give examples of the values of $x, y$. @user456, then they could either be in $\mathrm{Q}, \mathrm{R}, \mathrm{C} $, right?

Comment: yes they are int, but i want a function that directly gives the answer without stopping to 'check' if r is 0 or not

Answer (score 0):

Your examples suggest that $x$ and $y$ are integers.

Use use ordinary division to write

$$
x = qy + r
$$

where the remainder $r$ is between $0$ and $y-1$. Then when $r > 0$ your answer is $qy$. When $r=0$ it's $(q-1)y$.

Comment: we don't know if r is 0 or not as we don't know anything about x and y

Comment: Of course you don't. You find out when you do the division, then act accordingly.  This construction is a function, although it's not just a formula.

Comment: we have to write a function that doesn't check if r is 0 or not and directly gives the answer

Comment: @user456, suppose you code this. You are going to calculate $r$ within a function and output the result (which isn't likely to be $r$), right?

Comment: @Rohan yes but i can't use conditional statements

Comment: then you can't use loops as at the asm level that's all they are besides a compare and a jump.